# Implementing ViewModel & Repository for custom queries

Tags: java, android, android-room

I've been looking through examples online but I couldn't find any example of how the ViewModel and Repository would be implement for this query.

```py
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id = :userId")
    LiveData<User> getUser(int userId);
```

My attempt on this looked something like this

```java
     public class UserRepository {
        private UserDao userDao;
        private LiveData<List<User>> allUsers;
        private LiveData<User> user;
        private int userId;

        public UserRepository(Application application) {
            UserDatabase database = UserDatabase.getInstance(application);
            userDao = database.userDao();
            allUsers = userDao.getAllUsers();
            user = userDao.getUserById(userId);

        }
        public LiveData<List<User>> getAllUsers() {
            return allUsers;
        }

        public LiveData<User> getUser(int userId){
            return user;
        }
    }
```

```java
    public class UserViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

        private UserRepository userRepository;
        private LiveData<List<User>> allUsers;
        private LiveData<User> user;
        private int userId;

        public UserViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
            super(application);
            userRepository = new UserRepository(application);
            allUsers = ((UserRepository)userRepository).getAllUsers();
            user = ((UserRepository)userRepository).getUser(userId);
        }

        public LiveData<List<User>> getAllUsers() {
            return allUsers;
        }

        public LiveData<User> getUser(int userId){
            return user;
        }
    }
```

This resulted in a null Pointer Exception after trying set the logged in user details onto the navigation header.

```java
    View hView =  navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
    navHeaderUsername = hView.findViewById(R.id.nav_header_username);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
      if (intent.hasExtra(LoginActivity.EXTRA_ID)){

            int id = intent.getIntExtra(LoginActivity.EXTRA_ID, -1);
            if (id == -1) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Login Error!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }


            navHeaderUsername.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(userViewModel.getUser(id).getValue()).getName());
       }
```

Comment: First fix you code. at the end you are calling getUserById(..) which should be getUser(..) according to your posted code.

Answer (score 1):

I have also gone through this stage. The documentation is poor on this. They don't say this explicitly, but there is one extra step after retrieving the LiveData object.

Once you get the LiveData object by calling this:

```
LiveData<User> user = userViewModel.getUser(id);
```

Then, you need to do this:

```
user.observe(this, new Observer<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable User u) {
            // Do your stuff here
        }
    });
```

The `onChanged(..)` method is called when the data is available for doing your stuffs.

Hope this helps!!